# How are specific metrics calculated in Azure DevOps analytics for Sprints & Boards

Tags: azure-devops

I need to know how these metrics are calculated in Azure DevOps analytics for Sprints & Boards:

1. Completed percentage
2. Average Burndown
3. Total Scope Increase

(for the reports 'Count of work items' & 'Sum of remaining work')

I was not able to find exact details regarding the formula used to calculate these metrics in Azure DevOps documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your question, you can try the following calculation:

1.    Completed percentage
Completed=completed/（completed+remaining）

2.    Average Burndown

The meaning of Average Burndown is Average work completed per interval or iteration.
For example, the Average burndown in the image below is ‘-2’

[image]

The calculation process is：（（0-0）+（0-12）+（12-12）+（12-12）+（12-12）+（12-12））/6=-2

3.    Total Scope Increase

The meaning of Total Scope Increase is show how much work was added to the original scope since the burndown started.
The definition of an official document may also help you understand：
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/configure-burndown-burnup-widgets?view=azure-devops