# How is the average burnup and average burndown calculated?

Tags: components, scrum, scrumboard

I would like to know how the "average burndown" and "average burnup" are completed. Also, what is the formula for these metrics? I added the standard burnup and burndown charts in my dashboard.

[image: Burndown and Burnup Chart]

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57286236/how-are-specific-metrics-calculated-in-azure-devops-analytics-for-sprints-boar

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Comment: You can try asking in the PM stackexchange forum: https://pm.stackexchange.com/